# Swagger UI not loading in spring boot through springdoc openAPI dependency

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

By adding the dependency **springdoc-openapi-ui**, it is supposed to generate a swaggerui at http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html. However it didnt. How to understand why the springboot app is not loading the swagger UI ?

My dependency list

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.camunda.bpm.springboot', name: 'camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-rest', version:'7.15.0'
    compile group: 'org.camunda.bpm.springboot', name: 'camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-webapp', version:'7.15.0'
    compile group: 'org.camunda.bpm', name: 'camunda-engine-plugin-spin', version:'7.15.0'
    compile group: 'org.camunda.spin', name: 'camunda-spin-dataformat-all', version:'1.10.1'
    compile group: 'org.camunda.bpm.springboot', name: 'camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter-test', version:'7.15.0'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version:'2.4.3'
    compile group: 'com.h2database', name: 'h2', version:'1.4.200'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version:'2.4.3'
    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.5.2'
}
```

Comment: share your error logs and share your properties file and your config file too.